# MYSQL: select a set matching a condition generated by same set

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

i'm unable to explain correctly what i would achieve by the Title.
I will explain by example:

```
id=1, value=2
id=2, value=37
id=3, value=783
id=4, value=3
...
```

supposing i have a table like that above with autoincremental id and a random value,
i would select only the first rows for which the sum of values are less of 40.
so the result should be id{1,2}

Is there a solution by using a query or i need a procedure ?
Thanks you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use variables to calculate the cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@cume := @cume + value) as cume
      from table t cross join
           (select @cume := 0) vars
      order by id
     ) t
where cume < 40;
```

Comment: Should be **where cume < 40**, no?

Comment: This query works! I've used it to build another Update query here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501451/sql-update-from-a-complex-select

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
set @value:=0;
select id, value from
(
select @value:=@value+value as new_value, id, value from table
) as t where new_value<40;
```

Comment: i would use this query as part of UPDATE command.
in particoular i want to set a certain field when the new_value<40 ;
i tryed this but i get a sintax error:
UPDATE table SET skipbill=1 FROM (select @cumsec:=@cumsec+billsec as new_cumsec from table ) t WHERE new_cumsec<40 ;
where cumsec is the cumulative value of billsec.